# django: order and show name conflict

Tags: django, django-admin

i have a model using user as a forgignKey. and in the admin, i need it show as full name instread of username. then i applied

```
class CollaboratorInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Collaborator
    #list_display = ('collaborator__collaborator_first_name')
    extra = 0
    form =CollaboratorForm
    #raw_id_fields=("collaborator",)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        field = super(CollaboratorInLine, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
                                                db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.rel.to == User:
            field.label_from_instance = self.get_user_label
        return field
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        field = super(CollaboratorInLine, self).formfield_for_manytomany(
                                                db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.rel.to == User:
            field.label_from_instance = self.get_user_label
        return field
    def get_user_label(self, user):   
        name = user.get_full_name()  
        return name
```

it works fine as a dropdown list with fullnames. then i want to sort them in alphabetical order. 
then i appplied

```
class CollaboratorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    collaborator = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.order_by('first_name'))
    #assert False,collaborator
    class Meta:
        model = Collaborator
```

as this applied. the full names becomes username again. if i remove it, it becomes full names.
so how can i keep both features?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try subclassing `ModelChoiceField` and override the `label_for_instance` method to display the full name.

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField): 
    def label_from_instance(self, obj): 
        return obj.get_full_name()
```

Then use the new field in your model form.

```
class CollaboratorForm(forms.ModelForm):
        collaborator = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.order_by('first_name'))
        #assert False,collaborator
        class Meta:
            model = Collaborator
```

Comment: Hey Alasdair; 
it works for CollaboratorInLine. 
but how about the submitter in the report ,whcih is not a inline as following

class Report(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    summary = models.TextField()
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=True, related_name='report_submitter')

Comment: my bad i forgot to assign the form. thanks Alasdair it works perfectly.